# ant release --> ant: command not found

Tags: java, android, ant, android-ndk

I'm working to an Android application following the tutorial in this link (http://gaut.am/making-an-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract/).

Doing the point 2. I find some trouble inserting the commands in the shell. 
I solved the 'ndk-build' putting the command

"export PATH=$PATH:/android-ndk-r9b/ndk-build"

I solved the 'android update project --path .' using the command

"export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools"

(Please correct me if it is wrong). Then I had problems with the command "ant release". The terminal returns "ant: command not found". Is there something wrong? Hope that someone could help me

P.S: I already read other question similar to this one but they were different cases from this one. Hope that you could understand

Comment: is your ant path set?

Comment: I don't think so! Actually I don't know where 'ant' is... Yes I know. I should study it before doing something like that

Answer (score 3):

Put Ant in the path in .bash_profile

ANT_HOME=/home/you/apache-ant-1.8.3

PATH=$PATH:$ANT_HOME/bin

After exit the .bash_profile, you need to reload it with the command:
([dot] [space] .bash_profile)

$>**. .bash_profile**

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem changing the API of the version of the device. I don't know where the problem was but I did it to solve another problem and this one was automatically solved. Sorry for the disturb